# Spark Streaming vs Structured Streaming performance benchmark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Due to the fact that Spark's Structured Streams are pretty new API, there are situations when you have to fall back to older streaming API. For example, at this point you have a choice of AWS Kinesis + old streaming API vs Kafka + new streaming API.

*Are there any performance comparisons of Spark's old vs new streaming API? How many times the new API is better? Latency, throughput...*

Comment: Structured Streaming works with Kinesis: https://databricks.com/blog/2017/08/09/apache-sparks-structured-streaming-with-amazon-kinesis-on-databricks.html Can you cite an example of why you'd want to use the older API?

Comment: @maverik Structured Streaming works with Kinesis only on DataBricks platform. It's not open source. There is open source lib with few tens of stars on GitHub, without proofs it will work correct on prod

Comment: @maverik Because newer API claims to use all benefits off Dataset API (Catalyst optimization and Tungsten). It should have significantly better performance, at least in theory

Comment: Exactly, looks you are talking about "Micro-batch Processing" and "Continuous Processing" and their performance comparisons. Hope this slide can help you. [Share](https://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/whats-new-in-apache-spark-23-103606295)

Comment: Your Q is valid. Although I was wondering why you'd ever want to use the older version, not newer, and looks like it's because you're not on Databricks. A more pointed question might be how does that open source library benchmark against built in kinesis source. Also this doesn't directly answer your question but - the path of least resistance might be piping the kinesis into a kafka and using Structured Streaming on EMR so it allays your prod stability concern.

Comment: @maverik Do you  thinl that Kinesis => Kafka => Structured Streaming will be faster/better than Kinesis => Spark Streaming old API. Sounds like a big overhead  for me

Comment: Regarding Kinesis in Structured Streaming, open source its not made available. Qubole has written kinesis connector for Structured Streaming and open sourced as well for community: https://github.com/qubole/kinesis-sql Disclaimer: I work for Qubole